Detect Invalid Credentials passed to WebView2 control when using WebResourceRequested event
I have a generic solution that supports Basic and OAuth credentials to access web pages via the WebView2 control.  As I have to support both, I use the WebResourceRequested event to add the Authorization header.  I've noticed that depending on the content of the page I am calling I see multiple calls into this event and my code is adding the required Authorization Header each time.
My concern is, if the Credentials I add to the Header are incorrect, how do I detect that and handle as required, eg. prompt the user via my wrapper application to provide corrected details?

If the credentials are incorrect, the server should tell you.

Indeed, but what event would catch that as I don't want the user seeing a 404 or similar page displayed, I want control over the flow.

Often the status code will be 'Redirect' to login page, look for: 302 or in case of 'Basic authentication' it will be 401.

But in which event of the WebView2 control can I capture the error?

Try: CoreWebView2.BasicAuthenticationRequested Event: https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.basicauthenticationrequested?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.2792.45#microsoft-web-webview2-core-corewebview2-basicauthenticationrequested

Only works with Basic Auth - I need to support Basic and OAuth.

The event required is CoreWebView2.WebResourceResponseReceived this gives the Response Code from the failed call before showing the failed page to the user.
